# Selecting 1 cell to the left and 5 to the right of the active cell

Tags: excel, select, range, cell

I am trying to select and copy a row of 1 cell to the left and 5 to the right of the active cell in excel (the selection should include my active cell).

I have this draft code as example:

```
Sub ExtendAndCopy5CellsToRight()
    ActiveCell.Resize(1, 5).Copy
End Sub
```

BUT I need to select 1 cell to the left and 5 to the right of the active cell (the selection should include my active cell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to reset the starting position. The [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) controls the shape of the range to copy.

```
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 6).Offset(0, -1).Copy
```

Between your narrative and the sample, it was a little unclear on whether to resize 6 columns wide or 5. The above is set at 6 but should be easily changed.

Comment: this is selecting the cells in one row above the selected cell and to the right.

I need it to select one cell to the left and five cells to the right of my currently  selected cell in the same row.

Comment: I mixed up the row and column parameters in the `.Offset`. Fixed above now.

Comment: One to the left and five to the right and including active is seven. You are a better tea leaf reader than me.